# Отключить :before для одной из ссылок меню

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код:

```css
.menu_links a:before {
  content: "◆";
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}


/*Модальное окно*/

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "BrokgauzEfron", sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(246, 243, 236, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F6F3EC;
  border: 2px solid #7B6136;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);*/
}

.modal_dialog_for_visitors>div {
  width: 744px;
}

.close {
  background: #7B6136;
  color: #F6F3EC;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #C65B38;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu_links">
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка менюо</a><br>
  <a href="#open_modal_for_visitors">Ссылка меню на модальное окно</a><br>
  <!-- Модальное окно -->
  <div id="open_modal_for_visitors" class="modalDialog modal_dialog_for_visitors">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">X</a>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- --- -->
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a>
</nav>
```

Задача: отключить у кнопки на закрытие модального окна (X) псевдокласс :before.
Может можно вообще как-то проще написать?

Comment: `.menu_links > a:before` ? либо добавить класс к нужным ссылкам типа `a.menu-link:before`

Answer (score 1):

Добавить:  `.menu_links a.close:before { content: none; }`

```css
.menu_links a:before {
  content: "◆";
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}


/*Модальное окно*/

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "BrokgauzEfron", sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(246, 243, 236, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F6F3EC;
  border: 2px solid #7B6136;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);*/
}

.modal_dialog_for_visitors>div {
  width: 744px;
}

.close {
  background: #7B6136;
  color: #F6F3EC;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #C65B38;
}



 
.menu_links a.close:before { content: none; }
```

```html
<nav class="menu_links">
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a><br>
  <a href="#">Ссылка менюо</a><br>
  <a href="#open_modal_for_visitors">Ссылка меню на модальное окно</a><br>
  <!-- Модальное окно -->
  <div id="open_modal_for_visitors" class="modalDialog modal_dialog_for_visitors">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">X</a>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- --- -->
  <a href="#">Ссылка меню</a>
</nav>
```